# When is a subgroup the Weil restriction of another subgroup?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $M/F$ be an extension of fields. Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $F$, and consider the $F$-group $H$ defined as the restriction of scalars (a la Weil) of $G$ from $M$ down to $F$, i.e. $H=\mathrm{Res}_{M/F} G$. If $T$ is a subgroup of $H$, under what circumstances/hypotheses is it true that there exists a subgroup $\tilde{T}\leq G$ such that $T=\mathrm{Res}_{M/F}\tilde{T}$? Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** Since I did not get any response, I have cross-posted my question on MathOverflow (see this [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104372)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered in the comments to my [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104372).